# Is there a way to have multiple colours in a custom format? (NOT conditional formatting)

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-formatting

I've been asked if i can present a report with a ID format of 'RCA' in green, and a 3 digit number afterwards in black. is there a way of defining this in a custom for for excel? I've got this far, but it doesn't like my use of "{Black}"

```
[Green] \RC\A[Black] 000
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/review-guidelines-for-customizing-a-number-format-c0a1d1fa-d3f4-4018-96b7-9c9354dd99f5):

> A number format can have up to four sections of code, separated by
> semicolons. These code sections define the format for positive
> numbers, negative numbers, zero values, and text, in that order.
>
> ```
> <POSITIVE>;<NEGATIVE>;<ZERO>;<TEXT>
> ```

...

> To specify the color for a section of the format, type the name of one
> of the following eight colors enclosed in square brackets in the
> section. The color code must be the first item in the section.

These two statements together mean you can only define one color per section since any second color added in the middle of the section cannot also be the first item in that section. If you are open to alternate solutions, this would be possible by using two columns (left column right-aligned and right column left-aligned so they *look* like they're together) or VBA. There does not appear to be a built-in solution using custom formats, though.

Answer (score 0):

Need more details.

If you want to avoid VBA, it depends on how you are generating these numbers.

If the

- numbers are text strings
- and you generate them in sequential rows by filling down

You can format the first entry by

- Selecting `RCA` in the formula bar
- Select the Font color to be Green.
- Then select that cell and fill down

  - *The numbers at the end will auto increment*
- You could copy/paste these cells to other areas

[image]

***NOTE:*** *Now matter how you do this -- VBA or manually -- the cell will need to contain a text string in order to have different colors for different substrings.*